# What's the reward for completing Nightmare Mode?

Tags: rayman-fiesta-run

At the end of the Nightmare overworld, there's a big honking present.

[image: Screenshot of present]

If you tap it, it says you have to complete Nightmare Mode in order to open it. All 36 invaded levels, in a row, without dying.

I'll probably never be able to do this, but I'm curious: What's in the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just completed it. You get 10,000 lums and a another Rayman character ('Raywolf'). I was a little disappointed with the reward after all of that effort! I had already accumulated more lums just from the practicing and playing the game. Though, it was satisfying to finish it!

Answer (score 1):

My advice for anyone who wants to beat Nightmare Mode
-Play up to the First Invaded Level that annoys you
-Before playing it go and practice with the original invaded level until you're confident you can beat it without death
-Repeat

-Try to get a Golden Heart power-up if you still aren't confident
 -I haven't beaten it but the Strat works and Nightmare doesn't reset when I leave